# How do I activate custom action groups?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've created an action group to deploy my solar array, but now I'm safely in orbit, I have no idea how to actually do this. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as pressing the corresponding number (plus <kbd>alt</kbd>, possibly only on Mac).  I haven't tested if it works with the number pad, but I know it works with the number row.

Comment: *alt*, plus the corresponding number for me!

Comment: I don't need to use alt

Comment: It's not `alt+number`, it's just `number`. Also of note, I have mine bound to the "Toggle Gimbal" option, and for some reason it ignores the first press of the button - that might be messing you up.

Comment: @MBraedley Maybe the alt thing is a Mac thing

Comment: It doesn't work on numpad in my experiences.